# using '/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0' in phoneinfoga

Tags: development, dvb

I am using Phoneinfoga through Ubuntu and running the scan cmd, I am getting the following error:- using `/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0` and `/dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0`

```
main:2745: FATAL: failed to open '/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0': 2 No such file or directory
```